# Cannot deploy my app on a cloud provider

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-swarm, docker-cloud

I cannot start my swarm in docker cloud.

UNREACHABLE
Docker Cloud is receiving heartbeats, but cannot connect to the swarm
Resolution: Swarm is not publicly reachable, it may be behind a firewall or NAT